# Can't connect to mongodb with node.js due to mongoServerSelectionError

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When I try to connect mongodb with node I get this error.(In picture)
In many tutorial I have seen the solution of the problem can be found by whitelisting the ip address. but trust me I did but nothing happened.
This is my code

```
       const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require("mongodb");
// async function listDatabases(client){
//     databasesList = await client.db().admin().listDatabases();

//     console.log("Databases:");
//     databasesList.databases.forEach(db => console.log(` - ${db.name}`));
// };
async function main() {
  /**
   * Connection URI. Update <username>, <password>, and <your-cluster-url> to reflect your cluster.
   * See https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/node/ for more details
   */
  const uri =
    "mongodb+srv://bran:R8VP2F3ZvEZWRi5l@cluster0.hd6phlm.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

  const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });

  try {
    // Connect to the MongoDB cluster
    await client.connect();

    // Make the appropriate DB calls
    await listDatabases(client);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("the error: ", e);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}

main().catch(console.error);
async function listDatabases(client) {
  databasesList = await client.db().admin().listDatabases();

  console.log("Databases:");
  databasesList.databases.forEach((db) => console.log(` - ${db.name}`));
}
```

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42uRF.png)

This is the error I am getting:
MongoServerSelectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT 15.206.14.158:27017
at Timeout._onTimeout (E:\node-mongo-connect\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:293:38)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
reason: TopologyDescription {
type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
servers: Map(3) {
'ac-mg9lmct-shard-00-00.hd6phlm.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
'ac-mg9lmct-shard-00-01.hd6phlm.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
'ac-mg9lmct-shard-00-02.hd6phlm.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
},
stale: false,
compatible: true,
heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
localThresholdMS: 15,
setName: 'atlas-hltwao-shard-0',
maxElectionId: null,
maxSetVersion: null,
commonWireVersion: 0,
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
},
code: undefined,
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}

[This is the error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSCJX.png)

Comment: This is the error I am getting :MongoServerSelectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT 15.206.14.158:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: ok. I will take care of that next time

Comment: You can edit your question

Comment: edited my post.Please help me ou!

Comment: Maybe a firewall issue. Did you enable your IP in the MongoDB?

Comment: yes I did. and also I gave access from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue a week ago. When I add my corrent Ip address in the list  of network accesses in monogo atles, the issue was fixed. The important thing to mention that the 0.0.0.0 was not working.